# Yocto fails do_rootfs without detailed information for troubleshooting

Tags: yocto, rootfs

Yocto project ([homepage](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/index.html)) has very limited information while doing **do_rootfs** task. This task creates the root filesystem (file and directory structure) for an image.

When I did baking an image (via **bitbake** tool) and it returned 1 failed. But going through all logs, there's no information on how the task failed.

[image]

It is very hard to troubleshoot and fix the problem while doing rootfs.

What is the method to get more detailed log (error log) from the **do_rootfs** task?

Comment: Please use `-DDD` flag to print some debugging information, refer https://elinux.org/Bitbake_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried it but still not helpful for me now. The log is only "ERROR: Unable to install packages."  I expected that Yocto should show which package is unable to install, but It didn't show.

Comment: It should show error something similar to: https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2016-January/027975.html

Comment: We can't help you unless more information is provided

Comment: Thank you @GauravPathak . Actually, Yocto didn't show anything. I took a whole day to search in the long list of installed packages. I saw 2 packages didn't have files to install. But yocto didn't report something like: Cannot find <sth> or Cannot install <pkg>.